@InitBinder setDisallowedFields not working
In a Spring rest controller (using Spring Boot 3.3.1), I have a POST mapping method that populates a DTO like this :
@RestController
public class SomeController {
  @InitBinder("NoId")
  public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setDisallowedFields("name");
  }

  @PostMapping(path = "", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
  HttpEntity<Map<String, String>> createOne(@ModelAttribute("NoId") TestDTO dto) {
    // Should return {"dto":"TestDTO(id=1, name=null)"}
    return ResponseEntity.ok(Collections.singletonMap("dto", dto.toString()));
  }
}

@Data
@Builder
public class TestDTO implements Serializable {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
}

I don't know why but if I send a 'name' parameter via some form data, the DTO is loaded with its value instead of having its field 'name' set to null. So, for example it will return
{"dto":"TestDTO(id=1, name=John Smith)"} instead of
{"dto":"TestDTO(id=1, name=null)"}.

The solution was to add @NoArgsConstructor to the DTO class.
Without a no args constructor, the binder could not initialize the DTO's field name to null.
Note that I had to add @AllArgsConstructor otherwise the compiler would complain Lombok @Builder needs a proper constructor for this class.
So I added both and it works fine now.
